# Programming languages with FPGA

Tags: linux, c

What's the closest I can get to a C compiler if I use [linux-socfpga](https://github.com/altera-opensource/linux-socfpga) ? There seems to be no gcc but there is an awk interpreter. If I can use awk then it is ok but I would prefer C.

Comment: You want to compile C code on an FPGA?

Comment: @ThomasWeller If I can. I should also be able to compile it on my other system and then load it to the FPGA. It is an Altera DE2-115 with a design [done in QSys](https://github.com/montao/nios2mmu).

Comment: Well, it's possible to emulate a Z80 in a FPGA. The Z80 can execute assembly instructions. You could implement a C compiler in assembler and then let it compile your C code. I just wonder why someone would do this. Sounds like total overkill.

Comment: @ThomasWeller It is good as an exercise. I want to learn. I only designed 4-bit system and Z80 is 8-bit that I want to learn.